# How to add strings as a new column to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let say I have a dataframe, 3 rows, index and 1 column and separate 3 strings. How can I add those strings as a 2nd column to existing dataframe?

I have:
dataframe and 3 strings

```
1 Qwe
2 Asd
3 Zxc

s1 = Poi; s2 = Lkj; s3 = Mnb
```

I want:

```
1 Qwe Poi
2 Asd Lkj
3 Zxc Mnb
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataframe['new_col'] = [s1,s2,s3]
```